# Reference bandwidth smoothing in spatstat

Tags: kernel-density, spatstat

Is there any way to use reference bandwidth selection for kernel smoothing in spatstat package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Normal reference" bandwidth selection for two-dimensional point patterns is implemented in `spatstat` as `bw.scott`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wish to be available a package in which ecologists can perform different smoothing methods to compare which is very vital for making decision on selecting the optimal bandwidth.

Comment: I am still unclear what you mean by 'reference' bandwidth selection. Do you mean 'normal reference'? If you just want to compare the different existing methods for bandwidth selection, you can do that in `spatstat` using the functions `bw.scott`, `bw.ppl`, `bw.diggle` and so on.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare different methods. Spatstat is great option, but 'plug-in' bandwidth selection is missing there. Also, I wonder if it's possible incorporating physical barriers in producing KDE?!